# Storyboard file not able to access from Framework(iOS)

Tags: ios

I have made a framework in which one storyboard file exist, but there is one problem i am unable to access this file from another project in which this framework is imported, please suggest the solution.

Comment: Make it Public. then and only then it is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Project navigator**. **Select your project**. On the right side panel **select your framework** and from **File inspector** change your framework to **public**.